# Get DOM Element by Attribute in GWT?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, gwt

I want to add elements in GWT to the following element of a static html page:

```
<div data-id="test"></div>
```

When I would have used this:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

then I could have accessed the element with:

```
RootPanel.get("test").add(someElement);
```

This is only working when I use the id attribute.

**How can I access an element that uses an attribute like data-id as I showed in the first example and attach a Panel or a Widget on it?**

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support IE6/7, then you can go with JSNI:

```
Element querySelector(String selectors) /*-{
  return $doc.querySelector(selectors);
}-*/;
```

See http://caniuse.com/queryselector for the compat table.

Maybe GWT 3.0 will add this to GWT proper as IE6/7 support will definitely be removed (it's only disabled by default in GWT 2.6)

Now that you get the `Element` there's unfortunately no `RootPanel.get(Element)` method so the only way you can get a panel widget to which you can add other widgets is to use `HTMLPanel.wrap(Element)`.

Comment: Isn't there a native way?

Comment: When I say “Maybe GWT 3.0 will add this to GWT proper”, I imply that it's not available for now.

Comment: How would I append a FlowPanel to an Element?

Comment: You don't (unless the element is within an `HTMLPanel`, or it's not within a widget so you can use a `RootPanel`)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood your question. Updated the answer about the `RootPanel.get()` part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), you could match the element like this:

```
$("div[data-id='test']").add(someElement);
```

Comment: Isn't there a native way?